# Displaying data in a MVC Web Page when the number of columns are not fixed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, grid

I want to display the data in a Razor View in MVC from a customized datatype ('User' here) stored as a generic list. how to display that? the number of columns may vary, Is there a way to do this?

My code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(DataDTO data, FormCollection fc)
{
    string server = fc["CategoryName"].ToString(); 
        //"ctsintbmvodiaf1"
    string cacheName = data.CacheName;
        //"1CPlatformCache";
    string keyName = data.KeyName;
        //"UserContext_311581";
    try
    {
        DataDAO.Initialize(server, cacheName);
        var outPutData = DataDAO.dataCache.Get(keyName);
        if (outPutData != null)
        {
            if (keyName.Contains("UserContext_"))
            {
                var ucOutput = (CTS.OneCognizant.Platform.Caching.User)outPutData;
                CTS.OneCognizant.Platform.Caching.User userData = (CTS.OneCognizant.Platform.Caching.User)outPutData;
                List<User> _user = new List<User>();
                _user.Add(userData);
                return View(_user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the actual problem is? What did you try that didn't work? It would also be helpful if you could simplify the code and show just the relevant parts.

Comment: List<User> _user = new List<User>();
                _user.Add(userData);
I am getting the data from the cache in the above variable "_user". Now I want to bind it to a grid view. Is there a way to do it in MVC, as the number of columns returned are not fixed, so we cannot directly bind them in the view.

Comment: Actually, I'm migrating a project to MVC. In Asp.net it was binded using:
gridResult.DataSource = (DataSet)outPutData;
                    gridResult.DataBind();
Same way can we do it in mvc. so that the data can be binded dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the WebGrid HTML Helper that ships since ASP.NET MVC 3. Check out this [blog post](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=615) that shows how to use it. You can use it to easily render a grid of an "unknown" list.

You mention that you've used ASP.NET Web Forms databinding before, so if you imagine a simple GridView or DataGrid control, the WebGrid HTML Helper is fairly similar to that. A big difference is that the WebGrid helper does not have automatic edit/delete/insert support, so keep that difference in mind.